# How to make one string from a sentence capital in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to print `Hello MARK` in HTML. If I'm going to assign different styles to both the string using `<p>`tag then the text 'MARK' is coming on next line. I want to show as `Hello MARK`. So what could be the solution for this issue? Thnaks in Advance.

Comment: Wrap the text you want to capitalise in a `<span>` element.

Comment: try considering the answers :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `display: inline;`:

**HTML:**

```
<p>Hello</p>
<p>MARK</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
p { display: inline; }
```

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/uMNC4/)

`display:inline` means that the element is displayed inline, inside the current block on the same line.

Answer (score 2):

**HTML:**

```
<p>Hello <span class="capitalize">Mark</span></p>
```

**CSS:**

```
.capitalize {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```